# Anyway to mass delete Custom Metadata Type records?

Tags: metadata-api, custom-metadata, bulk-delete

I currently have 100+ records I need to delete under my custom metadata type, and I am not keen on having to do it one by one (I will need to reset the records every now and then as our requirements keep updating). I tried to do this via Apex but according to the documentation:

> Apex code can create, read, and update (**but not delete**) custom metadata records...

Comment: have you tried data loader to delete?

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy No, but my research tells me that it doesn't support custom metadata types. I've used the Custom Metadata Loader tool (https://github.com/forcedotcom/CustomMetadataLoader) but it doesn't have a delete function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As [Custom Metadata Records](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_custommetadata.htm)  are metadata you can use Force.com Migration Tool and [deploy the destructive changes](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

content of `destructiveChanges.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>CustomMetadataType.CustomMetadataTypeRecord</members>
        <name>CustomMetadata</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```

Comment: I have tried to delete it with destructive XML but still it remains unchanged, what part I am missing?
I have followed below points: 1. In Vs code retrieved the metadata record.
2. Put the record in destructive changes XML.
3. Remove the components from package.xml.
4. Deploy the destructive changes.xml

Answer (score 2):

If you can run Apex, here's how you assemble the list for the destructiveChanges.xml very quick. Note: replace { and } by corresponding angle brackets.
Copy paste the debug statements into your destructiveChanges.xml file.

```
List{String} objectTypes = new List{String}{
        SomeCustomMetadataType__mdt.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName(),
        AnotherCustomMetadataType__mdt.getSObjectType().getDescribe().getName()
};





System.debug('\t{types}');
for (String objectType : objectTypes) {
    List{SObject} customMetadataRecords = Database.query('SELECT DeveloperName FROM ' + objectType);
    
    for (SObject customMetadataRecord : customMetadataRecords) {
        String recordName = (String)customMetadataRecord.get('DeveloperName');
        System.debug('\t\t{members}' + objectType + '.' + recordName + '{/members}');
    }
}
System.debug('\t\t{name}CustomMetadata{/name}');
System.debug('\t{/types}');
```

Comment: Thanks, for your code, I'm able to generate descructiveChange.xml and execute undeployCode comment. Maybe you can just change your sample replace "{xx}" to "<xx>", since we are dealing with XML not JSON.

Comment: Angle brackets  are interpreted as html by the editor, hence the curly brackets.